# Azure API to get cost for a period

Tags: azure, api

I want to get the accumulated costs in Azure programmatically. Is there an API to get the information?
I have tried ratecard and usage details API but not sure how to get overall cost for a period.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage

Answer (score 0):

@Ankush Jain gave you exactly what you need, as far as a link goes. You should utilize the cost management API. You can use a POST command to query the Cost Management data.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage
[image]